# Copy And Paste In Non Html Table

Tags: html

We have a table

```
<div>
<div role="row">
   <div role="cell">1</div>
   <div role="cell">2</div>
   <div role="cell">3</div>
   <div role="cell">4</div>
</div>
<div role="row">
   <div role="cell">1</div>
   <div role="cell">2</div>
   <div role="cell">3</div>
   <div role="cell">4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to allow copy and paste so that each row and column would come out on an excel document? So 2 rows 4 columns wide with numbers 1,2,3,4 in 4 cells across (number per cell)?

Comment: I love this question! I never tried it, but maybe you could use the [selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object when detecting a copy event and then manipulate the content being copied to the clipboard? I created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kd5psvaL/) and if you copy anything and paste it to excel you'll see it paste "Hello world" into 2 cells